# Syncing Work and Home calendars

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I events on my home calendar and work calendar (both on Google calendar), I would like that every event created on whatever calendar will block the other calendar on the same time slot.
If the event gets updated (or deleted) this should be reflected as ell.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a service which does exactly that - block time in one calendar based on events from another calendar.

https://SyncThemCalendars.com

Give it a spin and let me know what you think :-)